# Zipping dictionary to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to zip my dictionary into a panda's data frame, and do it by the keys that are in the dictionary and not manually:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']}
columns = list(dict.keys())   # ['A', 'B']
manual_results = list(zip(dict['A'], dict['B'])) #  [('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')]
df = pd.DataFrame(manual_results, columns=columns)
```

I wish to create the results without the need to explicitly write the name of each key (dict['A'], dict['B'] etc). Any Ideas?

Comment: no need to zip, `pd.DataFrame(dict)` should do the trick.

Comment: And don't use `dict` as name, it's built-in type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to zip it.  Pandas can create a dataframe directly from a dict:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df)
```

```
    A   B
0  a1  b1
1  a2  b2
2  a3  b3
```

reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

---

Note: You can also orient it the other way (so the dict keys become the row index instead of colums) ...

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
print(df)
```

```
    0   1   2
A  a1  a2  a3
B  b1  b2  b3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `zip()` as [pd.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) natively expect the parameter `data` to be a `dict` that can contain Series, arrays, etc.

You can simply do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Which output:

```
    A   B
0  a1  b1
1  a2  b2
2  a3  b3
```